# Remove string using preg_replace. Is there any other alternative?

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I need to remove some parts of string at regular intervals based on simple `special characters like _ and |`. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$text = "a*a1.zip,a2.zip|b*b1.zip|c*c1.zip|d*d1.zip|e*e1.zip|f*f1.zip|g*g1.zip|h*h1.zip";
$expl = explode("|", $text);
print_r($expl);
?>
```

I need to remove all the `alphabets and *'s, |'s` such that my output should look like:

`a1.zip,a2.zip,b1.zip,c1.zip,d1.zip,e1.zip,f1.zip,g1.zip,h1.zip`

I am trying to use `preg_replace` but its very hard to understand `:(`. Is there any other alternative? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [preg_match](http://www.php.net/preg_match) instead, but you would still need to get your regex correct, so it wouldn't necessarily be any easier. If you would prefer to use something without regex, try a double [explode](http://www.php.net/explode):

```
$text = "a*a1.zip,a2.zip|b*b1.zip|c*c1.zip|d*d1.zip|e*e1.zip|f*f1.zip|g*g1.zip|h*h1.zip";
$expl = explode("|", $text);
foreach ($expl as $part) {
    // PHP 5.4+
    $values[] = explode('*', $part)[1];

    // OR PHP < 5.4
    $tempvar = explode('*', $part);
    $values[] = $tempvar[1];

    // Choose one of the above, not both
}
$string = implode(',', $values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I didn't test this. But you can get a hint

```
<?php
    $text = "a*a1.zip,a2.zip|b*b1.zip|c*c1.zip|d*d1.zip|e*e1.zip|f*f1.zip|g*g1.zip|h*h1.zip";


    $expl = explode("|", $text);

    // YOU HAVE TO REMOVE a*, b*, c* which will be the first 2 characters after exploding. avoid this first 2 characters using substr

    foreach($expl as $key=>$value) {

        $result[]   = substr($value,2);

    }

    $result_string = implode(',', $result);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

single liner without `preg_`

```
$result_string = implode(',',array_map(function($v){return substr($v,strpos($v,'*')+1);},explode('|',$text)));
```